# What is Lucius Malfoy's Boggart?

Tags: harry-potter

According Draco Malfoy's mantra is "My father will hear about this!",and what's his father's greatest fear?

Comment: Him being... *poor*, I guess? Begging the Weasleys for a crust of bread 

Comment: @Lefteris008 - He's certainly not overkeen on having his family killed in front of him

Comment: What is the link between the mantra and his greatest fear?

Comment: Being married to a half-blood or muggle. Voldemort.

Answer (score 7):

In brief, we don't know. There are (to the best of my knowledge) no writings on this subject, nor is it addressed in the books or films.

Lucius certainly does seem to have two key fears, either of which would potentially be a Boggart form for him.

- **Becoming destitute and losing his money, power and privilege**
- **The death of his family, and especially his son.**

That being said, it could easily be something more mundane like spiders or clowns.

---

Interestingly, Lucius' Boggart form in the [*Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4* video game](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Harry_Potter:_Years_1-4) is **Voldemort**, although it's worth pointing out that this is the default setting for any character without a canonical form.